# Colorbar resizes the subplots

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

I'm trying to plot 3 images side by side in MATLAB using `subplot`:

```
maxValue =  9;
minValue =  5;

figure(1)
subplot(1,3,1);
imshow(im1);
axis equal;

subplot(1,3,2);
imagesc(im2);colorbar;
caxis([minValue maxValue]) 
axis equal;

subplot(1,3,3);
imagesc(im3);colorbar;
caxis([minValue maxValue]) 
axis equal;
```

but the result looks like this:

[image: results]

Apparently the colorbar is resizing the image. How can I make all 3 images the same size and the colorbar fit the size of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is resized to maintain its aspect ratio according to the available space.
Use [`axis normal;`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#input_argument_d0e60776) for `subplot(1,3,1)` instead of `axis equal`.
 <sup>You might need to maximise the figure window as well.</sup>

---

For `im1 = imread('peppers.png');`, the result is:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
fig = figure(1);
set(fig, 'Position', [52 529 1869 445]); % Resize the image
subplot(1,3,1); % Add a subplot
subaxis(1,3,1, 'Spacing', 0.03, 'Padding', 0, 'Margin', 0); % Remove whitespace from subplot
imshow(im);
axis equal; % Use undistorted images


subplot(1,3,2);
subaxis(1,3,2, 'Spacing', 0.03, 'Padding', 0, 'Margin', 0);
imagesc(depth_gt);colorbar;
caxis([minValue maxValue]) 
axis equal;


subplot(1,3,3);
subaxis(1,3,3, 'Spacing', 0.03, 'Padding', 0, 'Margin', 0);
imagesc(depth_pred);colorbar;
caxis([minValue maxValue]) 
axis equal;
```

You can get this 'position' my manually resizing the image and then printing the output of `fig` in the Matlab command terminal